# Python - How to count how many If/Else statements exist

Tags: python, if-statement, count, python-3.10

I want to count how many If/Else statements are in my function.

My code looks like this:

```py
def countdown(type):
    if type == 1:
        //code
    elif type == 2:
       //code
    else:
        print(f"You have reached the end of the script. "
              f"The maximum type of countdowns are: {x}")
        exit(1)
```

Where the `x` is, there should be the number of if queries (If/Else). In this case, there are 3 queries. It should serve that if I create another if/else query within this function, I don't have to change the warning at the bottom of the script.

Is that even possible?

I'm using Python 3.10

Comment: You could load the source code file containing the function and then either use a simple text search (unreliable) or create an abstract syntax tree (module "ast") and process that.

Comment: This looks a bit like an X/Y problem. You can count statements in uncompiled code (as the above comment explains) but once in the code you can't easily count all potential codepaths, unless you ensure that hey are all visited, and 'log' that in some way. If you post again try to explain what the aim of your code is.

Comment: I want to count how big this `if statement` is. In this case, I can count 3. 1 for the beginning: `if type == 1:`, 2 in the middle: `elif type == 2:` and 3 for the bottom: `else:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Python 3.10 you can use a new [`match`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-match) operator. An example:

```py
def countdown(type):
    match type:
        case 1:
            # code
        case 2:
            # code
        case _:
            print(f"You have reached the end of the script. "
                  f"The maximum type of countdowns are: {x}")
            exit(1)
```

As for me, it is a more readable solution than a `dict` one.

What about counting the number of options, let's consider that we have `n` different and logically separated options. In this case, I'd advise you an [`enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#intenum):

```py
from enum import IntEnum
class CountdownOption(IntEnum):
    FIRST = 1
    SECOND = 2
    # ...

# ...

def countdown(type):
    match type:
        case CountdownOption.FIRST:
            # code
        case CountdownOption.SECOND:
            # code
        case _:
            print(f"You have reached the end of the script. "
                  f"The maximum type of countdowns are: {len(CountdownOption)}")
            exit(1)
```

Comment: What are the differences between `unknown_command` and `_`? How to set the variable `x` to how many cases there are?

Comment: What do you mean by `unknown_command`? `_` is an option that never fails to match. As it's written in docs, `Note the last block: the “variable name” _ acts as a wildcard and never fails to match. If no case matches, none of the branches is executed.`

Comment: Hm, I searched a bit and yeah, you have to be right. In the sources that I've found it's used exactly like `_`. So it seems to be an alternative. It's strange, though, that there is no such information at the original sources.

Comment: How to set the variable `x` to how many cases there are?

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: How to assign the cases names? For example: I want to call `case CountdownOption.FIRST:` with `start`.

Comment: You have to use actual cases names instead of `FIRST` and `SECOND` like `LINEAR_COUNTDOWN`. If I got you right.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `if..else`, but a dict or list:

```
types = {
    1: ...,
    2: ...
}

try:
    types[type]
except KeyError:
    print(f"You have reached the end of the script. "
          f"The maximum type of countdowns are: {len(types)}")
    exit(1)
```

What exactly to put into the dict as values depends… Can you generalise the algorithm so you just need to put a value into the dict instead of actual code? Great. Otherwise, put functions into the dict:

```
types = {1: lambda: ..., 2: some_func, 3: self.some_method}

...

types[type]()
```